# ms-access: single and double quotes in conditional formatting

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

does it matter which quotes i use when i do conditional formatting?

for example

`some_field='this'` or `some_field="this"`

does it make any difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When comparing to a literal, it does not matter, except if that literal contains a quote.

But if you're comparing to an expression, you would need to choose the appropriate quotes, but in a conditional formatting expression, you don't need them to test a control/field.